# Mistakes in FAQ for some SE sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling

I like the new "format" of the FAQ, but it looks like a few things broke:

[image: screenshot]

Furthermore, clicking on the "What kind of questions should I not ask here?" link doesn't do anything.

---

**Added by @kiamlaluno:**

Similar issue is present on meta.drupal.SE/faq, and meta.english.SE/faq.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

To make a comparison, the same issue is not present on drupal.SE/faq, even though both drupal.SE and meta.drupal.SE are using the same software revision.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Looking around, the overescaped entities seem to be present on every meta other than meta.SO.

Comment: Yep. It seems the problem is just on meta sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding issue will be fixed in the next build.

Clicking the `"What kind of questions should I not ask here?"` *does* actually do something even for non-expanding sections - it changes the URL hash in your address bar.  We want to expose as many ways as possible to allow linking to particular sections of the faq.  When you arrive at any section of a site's FAQ except the first (whatever that happens to be) we copy and highlight that section up top.

You can test it out here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask